# Count Unique Values with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel

I've been struggling with this for hours now, and I just can't figure out how to add a second criteria to my formula.

I have this table:

device #      date plan used

```
5     12/2/2017    A

8     12/3/2017    A

9     12/4/2017    B

56    12/2/2017    B

588   12/5/2017    C

56    12/2/2017    C
```

I am trying to get the **number** of unique devices, that are on plan A and have the date 12/2/2017. Here is the formula I have now.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D116005=G2,B2:B116005),IF(D2:D116005=G2,B2:B116005))>0,1))
```

I have successfully counted the unique devices with the criteria of being on 12/2/2017, but I just cannot figure out how to add additional criteria (i.e. on plan A). The G2 cell is where I am storing the date 12/2/2017 for comparison.

I have tried using IF(AND(.. but I can't seem to get it to work.

Could someone help me with this? Let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you,
Staci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiplication to return a 1 (equivalent to TRUE) if both match:

```
IF((Table1[date]=TargetDate)*(Table1[plan_used]=TargetPlan),Table1[device_'#],"")
```

Putting it all together:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((Table1[date]=TargetDate)*(Table1[plan_used]=TargetPlan),Table1[device_'#],""),IF((Table1[date]=TargetDate)*(Table1[plan_used]=TargetPlan),Table1[device_'#],""))>0,1))
```

Remember this is an **array** formula so must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

I used structured references and named cells, but you should be able to transfer to your cell references.

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you. Got it to work. Could you explain why the multiplying returns a 1 for true though?

Comment: Each equality part `(date_column = desiredDate)` will return an array of `FALSE` or `TRUE`.  eg: `{FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE}`.  When you multiply two, or more, of these arrays together, you effectively `AND` each element and return an array of `1`'s or `0`'s.  On the worksheet, `1` = `TRUE` and `0` = `FALSE`, so the `value_if_true` clause of the `IF` will return an array of device_#'s if and only if the array multiplication shows both parts match.  Use the Formula Evaluation tool on a small data segment to follow this better.

Answer (score 0):

in column D, starting in cell D2, put this formula:

```
=if(and(B2=date(2017,12,2),c2="A",countif($A$2:A2,A2)=1),1,0)
```

then just sum that column to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming plans in column `F` try this revised array formula:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D116005=G2,IF(F2:F116005="A",B2:B116005)),B2:B116005),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Notice that it's not necessary to repeat the `IF` functions I the "bins array" argument of the `FREQUENCY` function

Answer (score 0):

No formulas required: Simply whip up a PivotTable of the data, put Device and Date in the Rows field, and drag Plan to the Values area, which will automatically be given the COUNT treatment by the PivotTable because it's a text field.